# sed/awk how to add to the matched strings

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have text file which contains lines as mentioned below

```
<property>PASSWORD_X_1</property>
<property>PASSWORD_A_2</property>
<property>PASSWORD_B_6</property>
```

so on so forth..

Now i am looking to change the lines to:

```
<property>{PASSWORD_X_1}</property>
<property>{PASSWORD_A_2}</property>
<property>{PASSWORD_B_6}</property>
```

I could change the initial "{" using simple sed expression:

```
sed -e '/PASSWORD/{PASSWORD/g'
```

Not able to figure out how do i append the "}" character.

Any suggestions..?

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -e 's/PASSWORD_[A-Z]_[0-9]/{&}/'`

easy to modify!

Comment: Works like a charm! Didnt know that '&' means current matched string in sed. Thanks very much dav1d.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

`awk -F"<|>" '{ print "<" $2 ">{" $3 "}<" $4 ">" }' file.text`

Comment: This will break down if the password has a < or > character in it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Chisholm! One of the sed based solutions worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/PASSWORD[^<]*/{&}/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(">P",">{P") sub("</","}</");}1' file
```